# Copy one tar.gz file without scp(using echo or cat)

Tags: python, linux, bash, tar, scp

Is it possible for us to copy contents of a .tar.gz file using echo command?

I am using telnet(through telnetlib in python) to execute commands in a server. I need to copy few files into the server. However, scp just hangs after authentication. The server is a busybox server. Another team is looking into the issue for now. The scp command I used is this:

```
scp -i /key/private.pem /home/tempuser/file.tar.gz tempuser@remote1:/tmp/
```

I side stepped by reading the contents of the file, put them in the echo command in the remote. However, when I try to read a tar.gz file, it fails. I could not untar the file and copy the files within it as the tar file has nearly 500 files in it. Including a few tar files.

So any possible way to copy a tar file contents(read through open command in python) without scp?

Or is it possible to copy a file using the telnetlib in python? using the Telnet function?

To be more clear, I need to upload a tar.gz file from local machine to the remote machine. But without the help of scp. It will be more helpful if it is a python solution. If bash is the way to go, I could run os.system too. So python/shell scripting solution is what I am looking for.

If you need any more information, please ask away in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative method using the `base64` utility. By base64-encoding the file you wish to transfer, you'll avoid issues with any escape chars, etc. that may trip `echo`. For example:

```
some_var="$( base64 -w 0 path_to_file )"

ssh user@server "echo $some_var | base64 -d > path_to_remote_file"
```

Option `-w 0` is important to prevent `base64` from inserting line breaks (after 76 characters by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can `cat` and redirect, for example:

```
ssh user@server cat file.tar.gz > file.tar.gz
```

Note that `cat` will happen at the server side, but the redirection will happen locally, to a local file.

You could also directly gunzip + untar to the local filesystem:

```
ssh user@server cat file.tar.gz | tar zxv
```

---

To do it the other way around, copy from local to server:

```
ssh user@server 'cat > file.tar.gz' < file.tar.gz
```

And gzip + tar to the server:

```
tar zc . | ssh user@server 'cat > file.tar.gz'
```

Comment: When I tried the first suggestion, it gave me error that `/homedir/file.tar.gz: No such file or directory`. I need the cat to happen on local and upload the contents to the remote. Is that what this will do?

Comment: Oh I see. No, my first tips were from server to local. For the other way around, local to server, see my updated post

Comment: Thanks. However, getting an error saying `/bin/sh: {{hexa decimal value}}: not found`, and also `/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")`

Comment: This is the command I used: `ssh tempuser@remote1 'cat > file.tar.gz' < /home/tempuser/file.tar.gz`

Comment: The exact commands I gave you work for me. Perhaps you have a custom shell there that's not really `/bin/sh` ? Another idea, have you tried `sftp` command instead?

Comment: It is busybox shell in the remote and not sh. I will try with sftp and will update you.

Comment: This is a very low-tech way to copy files, simple redirection, it's very surprising if it doesn't work.... Do you know if the server has Bash at all or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91961/discussion-between-thiruvenkadam-and-janos).

Comment: @thiruvenkadam could you figure this out? Did you ask on Unix SE?

Answer (score 0):

if you try to the run the command outside of the python script it will ask you for password:

scp -i /key/private.pem /home/tempuser/file.tar.gz tempuser@remote1:/tmp/

to pass the password for Unix scp/ssh command you need to redirect the password as input to the command like:

myPass > scp -i /key/private.pem /home/tempuser/file.tar.gz tempuser@remote1:/tmp/

Comment: I am using the identity file without any passphrase. So even if I am to use it on bash, I don't need to give any password.

Comment: is it working for you from bash ? (outside of python)

Comment: need to point that the scp command should be ran from the host containing the file without ssh to the target, only info missing is your host OS and target host OS (unix/windoes/max)